# Remove marks on X-Axis

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, wpftoolkit

I use WPF toolKit to draw chart. I bind `List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>` to chart `DataContext` - as result i get chart with `LineSeries`. But on X-Axis there are some marks (what i mean - just small lines on Axis).

```
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="5.5,0,0,3"/>
```

When i specify X-Axis like

```
 <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X">
                                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.MajorTickMarkStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="Line">
                                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#bdb3ce" />
                                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness"  Value="0" />
                                        <Setter Property="X1"   Value="-4" />
                                        <Setter Property="X2"  Value="4" />
                                    </Style>
                                </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis.MajorTickMarkStyle>
                            </chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
                        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
```

it doesn't help, marks still on Axis.

How to remove that marks?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution on [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0753983c-c50a-45db-8d82-e8304deb8010/wpf-charts?forum=wpf).

I need specify my X-Axis as `<chartingToolkit:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>` and add Style to my Axis like :

```
<chartingToolkit:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" MajorTickMarkStyle="{StaticResource ChartMajorTickMarkStyle}"/>
```

where ChartMajorTickMarkStyle is next :

```
<Style x:Key ="ChartMajorTickMarkStyle" TargetType="Line">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</Style>
```

---

**NOTE** : I set style to CategoryAxis - I don't know why but when I set style to LinearAxis I get exception about problems with binding. I work with LineSeries, so I supposed to set style to LinearAxis but...